# Raise differing beeps

Tags: .net, vb.net, audio

I need to be able to raise different types of audio notifications to the user.  I need an "ok" and an "error" type sounds, I was hoping to be able to raise a simple beep and a critical stop type sound but I can only find the Beep() command which doesn't allow for differing sounds.  Is there a library that does what I need or will I need to roll my own using the system wavs.

Comment: You want the sound through PC speaker or sound card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the managed [SystemSounds class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsounds.exclamation.aspx) to play most of the default sounds. Use it like this:

```
' Plays the sound associated with the Exclamation system event.
SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play()
```

This API simply encapsualtes the Windows API function MessageBeep, that you could also use. Take a look [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/MessageBeep.html) to see its pinvoke signature.

Answer (score 2):

See [`Beep(int frequency, int duration);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
Beep( 750, 300 );
```

> dwFreq [in]
>   The frequency of the sound, in hertz. This parameter must be in the
>   range 37 through 32,767 (0x25 through
>   0x7FFF).
>   dwDuration [in]
>   The duration of the sound, in milliseconds.

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/messagebeep.aspx) is in C#, but see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in VB.Net, you've got the [My](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789188.aspx) namespace to play with, and if you look under [My.Computer.Audio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/081ed2x7(VS.80).aspx) you'll find the [PlaySystemSound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ct4t87(v=VS.80).aspx) command. This allows you to play whatever sound the user has setup for:

- the default Beep
- asterisk
- question
  mark
- exclamation mark

There's Intellisense and an [enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsounds(v=VS.80).aspx) that allows you to select the one you want, then it's just one line of code: `My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(Media.SystemSounds.Beep)`